# Need to query for users who have time conflicts, and return those time conflicts

Tags: php, mysql

This is a question that builds off of one of my previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541943/need-help-with-this-mysql-query-finding-users-who-are-available-at-a-certain-tim). The tables are the same:

```
Users
------------------------------------
UserID | Name      | Assignable
------------------------------------
  5    | John Doe  |      1

TimeSlots
-------------------------------------------------------
TimeSlotID | StartTime           | EndTime
-------------------------------------------------------
     3     | 2011-06-30 15:00:00 | 2011-06-30 16:00:00

Appointments
------------------------------------
TimeSlotID | UserID
------------------------------------
     3     |    5
```

The accepted answer helped me find users who were available for a certain time span. I need some way to input a start date/time and an end date/time and return any `TimeSlots` that conflict with those datetimes (they are in between the start/end dates, at the start/end times). But I need it to be organized by user, so:

If I input `2011-07-05` for the start date and `2011-07-07` for the end date, then I input `07:00` for the start time and `19:00` for the end time. And I have two users (User 1 and User 2), one who has no `Appointments` and one who has an `Appointment` on `2011-07-06 11:00`. I would need the results to be something like:

User 1: NULL
User 2: (Array of `TimeSlots` that conflict)

**EDIT:** Don't know if I was clear enough with the start/end dates and times. It would only look for conflicts between the start and end times on each date (inclusive) between the start and end date.

Comment: hi, i think you should describe bit more by entering 3-4 rows of data. because i dnt understand how can you recognize the user if he has not been appointed.? if user not appointed then how would be conflicted.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight modification on the previous answer - to catch those timeslots that start in your interval and end after it or start before your interval and end during it (technically still a conflict in your definition):

```
SELECT
   UserID
   GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(StartTime, ' - ', EndTime)) slots
FROM
   Users
   LEFT JOIN Appointments a USING (UserID)
   LEFT JOIN TimeSlots ts ON (
      a.TimeSlotID = ts.TimeSlotID
      AND ( ts.EndTime > @start AND ts.StartTime > @end
            OR ts.EndTime between @start and @end
            OR ts.StartTime between @start and @end )
   )
GROUP BY
   UserID
ORDER BY
   UserID
```

If you don't want to use concatenation, then just return each timeslot and convert the results into arrays in your php code.  In this case, your SQL will be

```
SELECT
   UserID,
   CONCAT(StartTime, ' - ', EndTime) slot
FROM
   Users
   LEFT JOIN Appointments a USING (UserID)
   LEFT JOIN TimeSlots ts ON (
      a.TimeSlotID = ts.TimeSlotID
      AND ( ts.EndTime > @start AND ts.StartTime > @end
            OR ts.EndTime between @start and @end
            OR ts.StartTime between @start and @end )
   )
ORDER BY
   UserID, StartTime
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL cannot return arrays, but you can come close with the following:

```
SELECT
   UserID,
   GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(StartTime, ' - ', EndTime)) slots
FROM
   Users
   LEFT JOIN Appointments a USING (UserID)
   LEFT JOIN TimeSlots ts ON (
      a.TimeSlotID = ts.TimeSlotID
      AND ts.EndTime > @start
      AND ts.StartTime > @end
   )
GROUP BY
   UserID
```

This will give you a comma-separated list (or NULL) of time slots per a user.